# Why nodejs close the stdout of process when waiting for a moment?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

```
const p = spawn('ls', ['/'])
console.log('$mark$')
p.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

The above code prints the file list of root directory accurately, which is:

```
$mark$
bin
boot
data
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
solr.log
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

However, if I waiting for a moment, such as 1 second, it prints nothing. The code is below:

```
const p = spawn('ls')
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('$mark$')
  p.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
}, 1000)
```

which only prints:

```
$mark$
```

I wonder why the second code does not prints any content of `ls` command.

The environment:

- Linux: openSUSE Leap 42.3
- Node: v8.11.1

Comment: I presume that's the complete listing. Now ponder this. Did it "close"? Or did the pipe simply never happen before the process exited? Think about that for a few moments.

Comment: By the time you pipe the stdout to process the `ls` command is finnished so there is nothing to print. There is **nothing strange about it**.

Comment: @Molda so how can I capture the stream after some time?

Comment: It should work just fine if the spawned process returns some more data later on. The `ls` command returns the data immediately and exits.

Comment: @Molda More data not work, it is just a simplest case for demostration. I have a command for about some seconds, but it must wait for another task before I can capture the output of the command.

Comment: @Run i created a bash script that prints some text every 5 seconds then i used your code with 3 second timeout and i get everything even data printed before i pipe stdout. It works as expected. I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Molda Why bash script and why before piping? I have edited my question and added more details. The second code really prints nothing, I have tested in my openSuse and centos system.

Comment: @Molda So no options to control it, I deal. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You still don't understand. The spawned process runs immediately so whatever it returns is lost since you didn't pipe its stdout anywhere. So if you want the data it returns later simply spawn it later.

Comment: @Molda Yes, I agree with you. It is the mechanism controls it.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code example, `ls` is long done with its output by the time you attempt to handle the output and pipe it.  Node.js isn't generally going to buffer an unused pipe for you.  You have to pipe it before the output begins or you will lose data, or you have to `.pause()` it.

Comment: So no options to control it, I deal.

Comment: @Run Of course there are options... as I said in my answer, pause the pipe and handle the output later.